# The grammar of "by as much" and "as much"

Tags: phrases

Which of the following is the correct sentence (maybe they are both correct):

Attacks are down as much as 10 percent.

Attacks are down by as much as 10 percent.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, the word *decreased* or *fell* is more common to use then *down* to show the decreasing amount of something.

Grammatically, the best sentence to write is the second one.

> The attacks decreased by (as much as) 10 percent.

If you didn't use *by* in there, it would slightly state that "something called `attack` decreased something else called `as much as 10 percent`.
Just like this:

> **The fund** reduced **the budget**
>
> > **The fund** reduced ***by* the budget**

The same thing implies to those sentence too (let's remove the `as much as` to make it more understandable):

> **The attacks** decreased **10 percent**.
>
> > **The attacks** decreased ***by* 10 percent**.

Still, it's the grammar rule that I'm talking about. Sometimes people omit the *by*.